# Integrating An Arbirtary Field inside a Circle (Formulation Only)

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a 2D mapping of some field that is parametrized by $x$ & $y$, $F(x,y)$. I want to integrate the values of the field that lie within a circle of radius $r$ and centered at $(x,y)$. How shall I formulate? I am interested in formulating the problem only. The following figure provides illustration.

[image]

Note: The field is a blackbox function so we cant evaluate integral directly.

Comment: Do you require subpixel accuracy ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Not really because the final measure shall be more or less an estimate

Comment: Then average the pixels such that $(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2\le r^2$.

Comment: Allright. If I have to have subpixel accuracy, how shall I go about then instead?

Comment: You need to weigh the pixels on the outline with an estimate of the overlapped area.